# File Handling in C - Removing specific words from a list in text file

Tags: c, file-handling

I am populating a short dictionary from my basic C program using the following code :

```
void main () {

FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary2.txt", "w+"); 

fprintf(fp, Word to Dictionary");
```

However I would also wish to remove certain words which I do not longer wish to be in the dictionary. I did some research and I know that

" You can't remove content from a file and have the remaining content shifted down. You can only append, truncate or overwrite.

Your best option is to read the file in to memory, process it in memory and then write it back to disk"

How can I create a new file without the word I want to remove ?

Thanks

Comment: Read the source file word by word, for each word you want, write it to the output.

Comment: "Your best option is to read the file in to memory, process it in memory and then write it back to disk." The "process" part is simply not writing the data you don't want in the file.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  and @ Some programmer dude Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You open two files: the one you've got (for reading) and a new one (for
  writing).
- You loop through the first file reading each line in turn.
- You compare the contents of each line with the words you need to
  delete.
- If the line does not match any of the deletion words, then
  you write it to the new file.

If the manipulation that you need to do is much more complex then you can literally "read it into memory" using mmap(), but that is a more advanced technique; you need to treat the file as a byte array with no zero terminator and there are lots of ways to mess that up.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Urwin for your input. My manipulation is not so complex so I will go or your first method.

Comment: When you've finished that you will end up with two files: the old one and the new one. You may want to replace the old one with the new one and there is a pattern to do that which is not obvious: After closing both files, first rename the old file. Then rename the new file to the original name, then delete the old file. If you don't do that and there is a problem, you can end up losing all your data.

Comment: Hi Richard, would you mind If I asked you a couple of questions on what you just stated above in chat ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code :

```
printf("Enter file name: ");
        scanf("%s", filename);
        //open file in read mode
        fileptr1 = fopen("c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary.txt", "r");
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
        while (ch != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c", ch);
            ch = getc(fileptr1);
        }
        //rewind
        rewind(fileptr1);
        printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
        scanf("%d", &delete_line);
        //open new file in write mode
        fileptr2 = fopen("replica.c", "w");
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
        while (ch != EOF)
        {
            ch = getc(fileptr1);
            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                temp++;
            }
            //except the line to be deleted
            if (temp != delete_line)
            {
                //copy all lines in file replica.c
                putc(ch, fileptr2);
            }
        }
        fclose(fileptr1);
        fclose(fileptr2);
        remove("c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary.txt");
        //rename the file replica.c to original name
        rename("replica.c", "c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary.txt");
        printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as follows:\n");
        fileptr1 = fopen("c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary.txt", "r");
        ch = getc(fileptr1);
        while (ch != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c", ch);
            ch = getc(fileptr1);
        }
        fclose(fileptr1);
        scanf_s("%d");
        return 0;

    }
```